# jquery to take textbox value and pass to controller action

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp

I have two textbox in form.

when i type some value inside textbox and click the button then i want to echo this value in my function.

I want to take value of my textbox and pass this in my controler function  on button click using javascript and ajax.

but my script is not working and not showing any value..

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#subvessels").on('click', function() {
            var shipment_title = $("#shipment_title").val(); //textbox value 
            var shipment_point = $("#shipment_point").val(); //textbox value  
            if (shipment_point) {
                var dataString = 'shipment_title=' + shipment_title;
                var dataString = 'shipment_point=' + shipment_point;
                var values = $(this).serialize();
                ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo Router::url(array("controller" => "DispatchedJobs", "action" => "approxBudget")); ?>',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: dataString,
                    dataType: "html",
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $('.spinicon').show();
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        $("#vessels_table").html(response);
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        $('.spinicon').hide();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>

//controller function
 public function approxBudget($shipment_point,$shipment_title)
    {
        echo $shipment_title;
        echo $shipment_point; exit();

    }
```

Comment: var dataString = 'shipment_title=' + shipment_title+'&shipment_point=' + shipment_point; Use this

Comment: Why would you use such complicated string build and overhead, and don't pass just the values by an object to jQuery? Mutch better readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the parameters as an object to `data`. This is everything you need.

```
$("#subvessels").on('click', function() {
    ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo Router::url(array("controller" => "DispatchedJobs", "action" => "approxBudget")); ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            shipment_title: $("#shipment_title").val(),
            shipment_point: $("#shipment_point").val()
        },
        dataType: "html",
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.spinicon').show();
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $("#vessels_table").html(response);
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('.spinicon').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

In php you get the values with `$_POST["shipment_title"]` and `$_POST["shipment_point"]` by default. If you use a framework, there could be other ways to access the values. But the request is correct like above.